# CruiseControl.net Fails A Build When There Are no Source Code Changes

Tags: mercurial, cruisecontrol.net

CruiseControl.net correctly detects that there are "No modifications detected" when I run the program with a visible terminal and shows green build reports but after I quit the program and start the service, the builds fail with the following stack trace:

```
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed: . Process command: C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe pull https://redacted.kilnhg.com/Code/Repositories/Group/HealthTracker
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.ProcessSourceControl.Execute(ProcessInfo processInfo)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Mercurial.Mercurial.HgPull(IIntegrationResult result)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Mercurial.Mercurial.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModifications(ISourceControl sourceControl, IIntegrationResult lastBuild, IIntegrationResult thisBuild)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request) 
Project: HealthTracker
```

System Information:

- Windows 7 x64
- CCnet  1.8.5.0

Where do I start to debug the problem?

Comment: What happens if you execute the above command on the server? It may give you more detail as to the issue

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "execute the above command on the server"?

Comment: CruiseControl is invoking this command: `C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe pull https://redacted.kilnhg.com/Code/Repositories/Group/HealthTracker`, what happens if you start that command from the command prompt? You'll need to check the working directory it should be invoked from. Typically this is the CruiseControl directory, if you haven't overridden it.

Comment: As you've identified this probably would have succeeded, the next step would have been to have been to run it as the `NETWORK SERVICE` account. Glad you've got it resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I use a token provided by FogCreek (documented at http://help.fogcreek.com/8375/access-tokens-and-continuous-integration-servers), I have a kiln.prefix, kiln.username, and a kiln.password. The three values are stored inside mercurial.ini. Unfortunately, there is no corresponding file for the NETWORK SERVICE user account so the solution is to run the CruiseControl.NET service with a normal Windows user account's credentials and configure that account with the correct mercurial.ini settings.

Answer (score 1):

When Cruisecontrol runs as a service it runs with the service account's credentials. It is probably running as network service. You will either need to provide a password for Mercurial in the ccnet.config file or you will need to copy your authentication certificates from your user account folder to the network service's account folder. That folder is in different places in different versions of Windows.